# turf.intersect of a turf.polygon and a turf.linestring?

Tags: javascript, turf

With the JavaScript library [`turf`](http://turfjs.org/), when I try to use `turf.intersect(polygon, linestring))` I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: 'coords' is undefined
at jsts.geomgraph.GeometryGraph.prototype.addLineString (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:15:12334)
at jsts.geomgraph.GeometryGraph.prototype.add (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:15:11273)
at jsts.geomgraph.GeometryGraph (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:15:9430)
at jsts.operation.GeometryGraphOperation (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:7:9064)
at jsts.operation.overlay.OverlayOp (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:7:16807)
at jsts.operation.overlay.OverlayOp.overlayOp (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:7:17248)
at n.prototype.getResultGeometry (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:13:17602)
at n.overlayOp (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:13:17228)
at jsts.geom.Geometry.prototype.intersection (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:2:20228)
at e.exports (http://localhost:6235/Scripts/turf.min.js:17:18325)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's an error with that version of the jsts library. Looks to be resolved with this commit. 
https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/pull/180/files